# how to find selected check box from FieldSet

Tags: jquery

I have a field set

```
<FieldSet>
<legnd>Studnetinfo</legend>
 <intpu type="checkbox">

  and here I am having StudnetId,FristName,lastname textboxes

</Fieldset>

 $('#btnAll').click(function() {
            $('#Details input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        });
```

on button click i am checking all checkboxes and I have other button on the Filedset which i submit.

When I submit clicks I need to send only which ever is checked from Fieldset?

Comment: Your question isn't terribly clear and you've got typos all over your code. Which button is checking the checkboxes, the submit?

Comment: Hmm the button SelectAll Checking all checkboxes.. after selecting I need to click submit to send other page only selected id's

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a useful link for you and seems to do what you need.

http://drupal.org/node/116548

From that article:

```
$("input[@type=checkbox][@checked]").each(
function() {
   // Insert code here
  }
);
```

Comment: That is a very old article, not more `@` on the attribute selectors, a simple `:checked` will work as well :)